# jqGrid integration with existing Durandal solution

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, durandal

I am trying to integrate jqGrid in my solution using Durandal to display records from dB in a grid view and with capability of adding a editable row to the grid. After looking at few examples I started the implementation but get an error"Uncaught Error: Failed to load routed module (viewmodels/jqGridBinding). Details: Object [object Object] has no method 'jqGrid' ".

My view file is (jqGridBinding.html)

```
<section>
    <table id="list2"></table>
    <div id="pager2"></div>
</section>
```

My viewmodel class is jqGridBinding.js
    define(function () {

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
    url: '/api/incidents',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { page: "1", rows: "20" },
    dataType: 'json',
    colNames: ['IncidentId', 'Title', 'Description'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 55 },
        { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', width: 90 },
        { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', width: 100 }
    ],
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    pager: '#pager2',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption: "JSON Example"
});`


jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
```

});

can someone look into this issues and suggest any solutions? Appreciate any input.

Comment: I hope this documentaion help to you.. http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs

Answer (score 1):

check this it has working jqgrid in durandal

> http://durandal-playground.azurewebsites.net/#/jqGrid-sample

Thanks,

Comment: Great sample! Is it open source?

Comment: Davi, you can have more samples from durandal website http://durandaljs.com/downloads.html. It didn't cover the jqgrid as asked before. But I also able to render the jqgrid by using the following changes in main.js files of HTML Samples.zip.  Added the folloing changes in requirejs.config({ setting of main.js.   ,'jqgridlocale': 'http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en'
    ,'jqgrid': 'http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min'

Comment: and added the related styles in index.html something like that  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="lib/JQGridReq/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" > </link>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/JQGridReq/ui.jqgrid.css" >    </link>